# Why is the number Pi more popular than any other constant?

Tags: soft-question, philosophy, constants

What is so special about the number $\pi$? There are many more interesting constants,
such as

e, $\gamma, \sqrt{2}$ or the catalanian number.

$\pi$ has been calculated to more digits than any other irrational number.

$\pi$ is the only number used in memory contests. There is even a pi-day, the
14th March.

Is there any reason for that ?

Comment: Sociological [snowball effect](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Snowball_effect).

Comment: Because it's been around the longest and it is used the most especially in everyday math and schools.

Comment: It's probably due to the movies [Life of pi](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Life_of_Pi),[Pi](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pi_%28film%29) and the fact it sounds like a [dessert](http://sidoxia.files.wordpress.com/2012/10/apple-pie.jpg).

Comment: What makes these constants more "interesting" than $\pi$? What does "interesting" mean? Honestly, this question seems pretty pointless to me, especially since it has extremely little relevance.

Comment: Also golden ratio is quite popular for obvious reasons. If common people knew more math I bet it would be the most popular.

Comment: I think this is a sociological question rather than a mathematical one.

Comment: Maybe because leaving a large number of (possibly) pointless questions just worsens the signal to noise ratio of the site?

Comment: There is also a [$\tau$ day](http://tauday.com/).

Comment: There are many radicals, and the square is but one among an infinite number of rectangles, but all circles and ellipses are tied to a single constant, $\pi$, which cannot even be expressed in radicals at all.

Comment: The Mathematical Association of America has already debated $\pi$ versus e here: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=whpAX30vjoE and answers you question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Apparently because is the oldest one! It is 2500 years old!

Comment: What about $\sqrt{2}$ ? Is $\pi$ really older ?

Comment: It is easier so speak $\pi$ than square root of two on the TV.

Comment: The proof of irrationality (inconsumerable ratios) is believed to have happened c. 380 BC, whereas $\pi$ was defined, as the the ratio of circumference and diameter by the early Pythogoreans, 6th centrury BC.